# Oracle PL SQL CASE in WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, case, where-clause

I know i could probably accomplish this by easily putting two whole statements in a CASE statement itself, but i'm new to SQL and trying to learn to write this the most efficient and intelligent way without duplicating any logic, and so i figure maybe there is a way i can turn a where condition line on or off basically.

I have the following statement(which doesn't work btw, missing a keyword it says):

```
      OPEN O_CURSOR FOR
       SELECT S.STORE_NO_4_DIGIT AS STORE_NO, S.STORE_NAME
         FROM RFS.RF_STORE S
        WHERE S.TYPE_CODE != 'W'
        AND
            CASE I_CAN_BE_CLOSED
                WHEN 0 THEN
                S.CLOSE_DATE IS NULL
            END                
     ORDER BY S.STORE_NO_4_DIGIT;
```

There is two cases based on the input variable I_CAN_BE_CLOSED, values 0 or 1.

In one case i want to allow it to return stores with only NULL CLOSE_DATES, and in the other case i want it to return either(both closing and non-closing stores).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE expression cannot return boolean in Oracle SQL. This should be equivalent, provided that I_CAN_BE_CLOSED is never NULL:

```
  OPEN O_CURSOR FOR
   SELECT S.STORE_NO_4_DIGIT AS STORE_NO, S.STORE_NAME
     FROM RFS.RF_STORE S
    WHERE S.TYPE_CODE != 'W'
    AND (I_CAN_BE_CLOSED != 0 OR S.CLOSE_DATE IS NULL)
 ORDER BY S.STORE_NO_4_DIGIT;
```

**Edit:**

In fact both answers given here are correct... Easiest way to verify is to write down every case in a truth-false table:

```
I_CAN_BE_CLOSED  S.CLOSE_DATE  [1]                      [2]   
0                 NULL          FALSE OR TRUE = TRUE    (TRUE AND TRUE) OR FALSE = TRUE
0                 NOT NULL      FALSE OR FALSE = FALSE  (TRUE AND FALSE) OR FALSE = FALSE
1                 NULL          TRUE OR TRUE = TRUE     (FALSE AND TRUE) OR TRUE = TRUE
1                 NULL          TRUE OR FALSE = TRUE    (FALSE AND FALSE) OR TRUE = TRUE

[1] == "I_CAN_BE_CLOSED != 0 OR S.CLOSE_DATE IS NULL"
[2] == "((i_can_be_closed = 0 and s.close_date IS NULL) or (i_can_be_closed = 1))"
```

Comment: Sorry. Justin beat you to it... not sure if this would work though unless i don't understand how oracle would execute this. If the first statement is true, does it not continue to the second?

Comment: Ok, i got around to this again, and i tried this out, and i realized this is the more elegant solution. I wasn't sure at first because i didn't know how SQL would process both statements if it found the first to be true. But it does not, so therefor you don't need the 'or' like in Justin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to `OR` together a couple of predicates

```
AND ((i_can_be_closed = 0 and s.close_date IS NULL) or
     (i_can_be_closed = 1))
```